# Is it possible to simply open a text file using swift

Tags: swift, file-handling

I'm researching building some some simple command line tools for a small side project and am evaluating swift as an option.

I love the expressiveness of the language but a lot of the examples I see are for safety critical scenarios which naturally require a lot of checking and some relatively complex mechanisms.

However in my case I'm not too concerned with safety and am looking for the simplest way to open and read a text file, my ideal scenario is some kind of method akin to python's `open("fileurl").read()` or C#'s `System.IO.File.ReadAllText ("fileurl")`

Is this possible?

Comment: Simplest form `let text = String(contentsOfFile:"/path/to/file.txt")` but in iOS and sandboxed macOS apps you can't pass this kind of literal full path in all cases. Caring for safety is not evil ;-)

Comment: See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1414831-init

Comment: absolutely not! :) I wouldn't want to play down safety, just curious about different ways of doing things in different contexts